# Configure The MDS web front end on a different server to the database

Tags: sql, iis, sql-server-2016, master-data-services

The current server set up is that IIS is installed on one server and the SQL Databases are on another server.
I need to install MDS where the Database is on server 1 and the web front end  (IIS) is on server 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the having the front end on another server is to install MDS on the server you want the front end to be hosted on and during the set up of MDS on the front end server to point the database to the database server.